# TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a POP UP using a Modal in angular js.I am facing and issue.Its says.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined.
>   Its throwing at $modal.open statement.

The code for config as below :

```
homeModuleApp.config(function ($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    //templateUrl: '/app/ng/modules/home/partials/login-partials-view.html',
    //controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl'
    onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/app/ng/modules/home/partials/login-partials-view.html',
        resolve: {},
        controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl'
      }).result.then(function (result) {
        // $scope.$close
        alert('result ->' + result);
      }, function (result) {
        // $scope.$dismiss
        alert('dismiss ->' + result);
      }).finally(function () {
        // handle finally
        console.log('Hello....');
      });
    }

  })
});
```

Can anyone guide me what could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Well if you get "undefined" error, you have to ask yourself why is it undefined and what it should be. In your code you simply inject $modal, but what is $modal? There is no $modal in angular by default, do you have some angular module with $modal service/factory injected?

Comment: You haven't injected it (like you have injected `$stateProvider`); however, since it is a service, it would not be available at the time of a `module.config()` section.  Also, different Tom :)

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the reply.I am new to angular Can you please help me how to implement the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, [here](http://jsbin.com/tekagahupo/1/edit?html,js,console,output) I've put together a jsBin which demonstrates how to do this with your code.

You can't use the `$modal` service in your `.config` section, as `services` are not available at that state of Angular bootstrapping (perhaps some `$modalProvider` is, but I'm not sure).  So, you can set the state up to go to some log in page, like:

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'loginController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
})
```

And then in that controller, you can use an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to trigger as soon as the controller is loaded, which will include your `$modal.open` code, like:

```
.controller('loginController', function($modal) {
  (function() {
    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'loginModal.html',
      controller: 'loginModalController', 
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    }).result.then(function (result) {
      alert('result ->' + result);
    }, function (result) {
      alert('dismiss ->' + result);
    }).finally(function () {
      console.log('Hello....');
    });
  })();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.Its working.Can you please provide some refrence to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be the injection of `MatDialog` into the constructor like:

```
constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public dialog: MatDialog
)
```